# How to know when Google Maps has repositioned a or all Markers after Pan

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events, google-maps-markers

I use `map.panTo(perthLatLng);` to move a map. I then wait for idle event `addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', panDone);` So far so good but, at "panDone" time, my map marker is still in the "old" screen Top/Left position and has not migrated to its new location x/y.

Is there an event or other heuristic that will let me know when Google Maps has finally synchronized my marker position with the new Pan?

Comment: why would the marker move if you pan the map?

Comment: @jpoehnelt you'd have to ask Google. In previous map API versions this operation used to be atomic but, sadly, no more. If the center of my map is New York and that is also where my Marker is, and I pan to Los Angeles, my marker follows New York sometime *after* the tiles have panned. See my answer/solution below for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Because of the maps API key you can not run the testmap.html file directly from Github but you can copy [testmap.html](https://richardmaher.github.io/Brotkrumen/testmap.html) to your file system and activate (double-click or file:// URL) from there.

Below is a complete SSCCE of my best effort strategy to solve this conundrum. I employ CSS transitions to: -

1. Detect when the Maps API has finally relocated my Marker after the Pan
2. Smoothly, transition my Marker to the next location on it's journey

NB: I will shortly update [Brotkrumen](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen) with a whole lot of new code as soon as I get the "Replay" functionality to work :-(

Note also, that to run the example below, just copy the code to a HTML file and click on it. But before doing that you'll also have to take a copy of [Hansel and Gretal](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen/blob/master/hg.png) to the same folder.

If you have another/better way to trap Google-Map-API-PanTo-Really-Really-Finished then please let me know. The "Idle" event is good for knowing when the map tiles are in place but that's it.

PS. If there are people out there that believe that CSS Transitions add no value here and this should be done with existing stutter libraries then please don't clutter this question with same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Smooth Runnings</title>

    <script type="application/javascript">
        'use strict';
        
/* identification division.
 * program-id.    GotTheMovesLikeJagger.
 * author.        Richard Maher.
 * version.       1.0
 */
        
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", isDOMIsGood); 
        
        const MARKER_SELECTOR       = "img[src*='hg.png'";
        const MARKER_SRC            = "http://localhost/hg.png";                    
        const myLatLng              = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };
        
        var mapDiv, protagonists, HandG, map, observer, markerDiv,
            markerStyle, travelListener;
        
        var dest =  [
                    { lat: -31.9523, lng: 115.8613 }, 
                    { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2093 }, 
                    { lat: -27.4705, lng: 153.0260 },
                    { lat: -34.9285, lng: 138.6007 }
                    ];
                    
        var destIndex   = 0;
        var touchDown   = false;
        
        function isDOMIsGood(e) {
            console.log("DOM");
            mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
        }
        
        function initMap() {
            console.log("Init");
            
            map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
                zoom: 4,
                center: myLatLng,
            });
            
            observer = new MutationObserver(waitForMarker);
            
            protagonists = {size: new google.maps.Size(45, 40),
                            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(45, 40),
                            url: MARKER_SRC};
                            
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'tilesloaded', tilesUp);
        }
        
        function tilesUp() {
            console.log("Map Tiles Here");

            travelListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', centerChanged);
            
            observer.observe(mapDiv, {
                            childList     : true,
                            subtree       : true ,
                            attributes    : true ,
                            characterData : false
                            });
                    
            HandG = new google.maps.Marker(
                {
                position: myLatLng, 
                map: map, 
                draggable: false,
                title: "HandG", 
                zIndex: 12, 
                visible: true, 
                icon: protagonists, 
                optimized: false
                });                     
        }
        
        function makeDestCenter(){
            console.log("Panning to new Center");           
            map.panTo(dest[destIndex]);
        }
        
        function centerChanged() {
            console.log("Center changed Left = " + markerStyle.left + " Top = " + markerStyle.top);
            markerDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
            markerDiv.style.transitionDuration = "1ms";
            markerDiv.style.transitionTimingFunction = "linear";
            markerDiv.style.transitionProperty = "left, top";
            markerDiv.addEventListener('transitionend', quiesced, { 'once': true });
            markerDiv.addEventListener('transitioncancel', quiesced, { 'once': true });
        }
                
        function quiesced(e) {
            markerDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
            console.log("Quiesced " + e.type + " left " + markerStyle.left + " top " + markerStyle.top);
            setTimeout(handover, 0);
        }
        
        function handover(e) {
            console.log("in handover left " + markerStyle.left + " top " + markerStyle.top);
            markerDiv.style.transitionDuration = 2000 + "ms";
            markerDiv.style.transitionTimingFunction = "linear";
            markerDiv.addEventListener('transitionend', incrSteps, { 'once': true });
            markerDiv.style.transitionProperty = "left, top";
            HandG.setPosition(dest[destIndex]);
        }
        
        function startLeg(e) {
            console.log("start leg " + e.propertyName + " left " + e.target.style.left + " top " + e.target.style.top);
        }
        
        function cancelLeg(e) {
            console.log("Cancel leg " + e.propertyName + " left " + e.target.style.left + " top " + e.target.style.top);
            markerDiv.style.transitionDuration = "0s";
        }
        function incrSteps(e) {
            console.log("Incr Steps " + e.propertyName + " left " + e.target.style.left + " top " + e.target.style.top);
            if (++destIndex >= dest.length) {
                console.log("Journey's end");
                markerDiv.style.transitionDuration = "0s";
                travelListener.remove();
                return;
            }

            setTimeout(makeDestCenter,0);
        }
        
        function waitForMarker(mutations, myInstance) {
            outer:
            for (var i=0; i<mutations.length; i++){
                if (mutations[i].type           == "attributes" && 
                    mutations[i].target.tagName == "IMG"        &&
                    mutations[i].target.src.toLowerCase().indexOf(MARKER_SRC) != -1){
                    touchDown = true;
                    break outer;
                }
                if (mutations[i].type != "childList" ||
                    mutations[i].addedNodes.length   == 0) 
                    continue;
                for (var j=0; j<mutations[i].addedNodes.length; j++) {
                    var node = mutations[i].addedNodes[j];
                    if (node.tagName == "DIV" && node.firstChild && node.firstChild.tagName == "IMG" &&
                        node.firstChild.src.toLowerCase().indexOf(MARKER_SRC) != -1){
                        touchDown = true;
                        break outer;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (touchDown) {
                console.log("Got Marker");
                myInstance.disconnect();
                var markerImgs = document.querySelectorAll(MARKER_SELECTOR);
                if (markerImgs.length != 1) {
                    throw new Error("Expecting one and only one Hansel and Gretal. Found: " + markerImgs.length);
                };
                markerDiv = markerImgs[0].parentNode;
                markerStyle = getComputedStyle(markerDiv);
                markerDiv.addEventListener('transitionstart', startLeg);
                markerDiv.addEventListener('transitioncancel', cancelLeg);
                console.log("Left = " + markerStyle.left + " Top = " + markerStyle.top);
                setTimeout(makeDestCenter,0);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&v=weekly&channel=2" async
    ></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map {
          height: 100%;
        }

        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        html,
        body {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey